# Group a list of composite objects

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

I have an ArrayList(Result) where the Result objects all holds a reference to an Event object. There are maybe 50 Result objects in the ArrayList but only 5 different Event objects. Is there a way to loop through the ArrayList and group together Results that have identical Event.getName() references?

I want to separately run a method on results in the event 'high jump', then only on results in the event 'long jump', etc. 
I will not know beforehand what events my result list holds as they are created from user input.

I know how to sort the ArrayList on event name, but I want to rather split the list by event and store them in other temporary lists (?)

from Result class:

```
public Result(double result, int attemptNumber, Participant participant, Event event) {
    this.result = result;
    this.attemptNumber = attemptNumber;
    this.participant = participant;
    this.event = event;
}
```

from Event class:

```
public Event (String eventName, int attemptsAllowed) {
    this.eventName = eventName;
    this.attemptsAllowed = attemptsAllowed;
}

public String getEventName() {
    return eventName;
}
```

Result objects are stored unsorted in an ArrayList called allResults, here is a method in a third class that sorts and trims a copy of allResults (called resultByEvent) based on input eventName and keeps only the highest result per participant:

```
public ArrayList<Result> resultsByEvent(String eventName) {
    resultsByEvent.addAll(allResults);

    for(int i = 0; i < resultsByEvent.size(); i++) {
        Event event = resultsByEvent.get(i).getEvent();

        if(!event.getEventName().equals(eventName)) {
            resultsByEvent.remove(i);
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(resultsByEvent, new EventLeaderboard());

    for(int n = 0; n < resultsByEvent.size(); n++) {
        for(int j = n + 1; j < resultsByEvent.size(); j++) {
            Participant participant1 = resultsByEvent.get(n).getParticipant();
            Participant participant2 = resultsByEvent.get(j).getParticipant();

            if(participant1.getParticipantId() == participant2.getParticipantId()) {
                resultsByEvent.remove(j);
                j = j - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return resultsByEvent;
}
```

The above is what I want to run on all my events in the original result list.

Comment: Can you post the code for `Result` and `Event`?

Comment: share some code that you've worked on please

Comment: Are you on `java-8`?

Comment: I shared some code above, I am very new to Java (yes I'm on java-8)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to group all your events by name?

Comment: Yes exactly, group Events by equal getEventName()

Comment: @AgnesAronsson See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the `Stream` API :

**Group events by name**

```
Map<String, List<Event>> eventsGroupedByName = allResults.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getEvent().getName()));
```

**Group results by event name**

```
Map<String, List<Result>> resultsGroupedByEventName = allResults.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.getEvent().getName()));
```

Comment: This looks cleaner, I will try it straight away. Thank you!

Comment: @AgnesAronsson Your comment on the question said *Yes exactly, group Events by equal getEventName()* but looks like you want to group results by event name. I have provided both solutions in Java-8.

Answer (score 3):

You may create a *eventsResults* `Map` of "event name"/"list of corresponding results", then when you are looking for results matching some name, just call `List<Result> matchingResults = eventsResults.get(<some event name>)`.

In the following example, `results` is your `List<Result>` .

```
        Map<String,List<Result>> eventsResults = new HashMap<String,List<Result>>();

        for(Result result : results){

            String eventName = result.getEvent().getEventName();
            // search the map for this event name
            List<Result> storedResultsList = eventsResults.get(eventName);

            if(storedResultsList == null){
                // no entry for this name yet, let's create one
                List<Result> newEventResultsList = new ArrayList<Result>();
                newEventResultsList.add(result);

                eventsResults.put(eventName, newEventResultsList);


            }
            else{
                // entry found, let's add this result to the list
                storedResultsList.add(result);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is working, exactly what I needed :)

Comment: @AgnesAronsson You said that you are using `java-8`, I highly recommend using the new `Stream` API for transformations of this nature. See my answer instead.

Comment: @Berger Maybe you should use `Map::computeIfAbsent` like `eventsResults.computeIfAbsent(eventName, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(result);`

Answer (score 0):

You could do a map of  lists. Key = reference, data = lists of that type of reference.

Comment: I think you mean a `Map`, not a `Set`. Even then, to make this answer useful, please provide some sample code.